# How to give multiple input datasets files to a single DBscan clustering algorithm

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, dbscan

[image: Input dataset text files]am working with gene expression fies, i have a folder with name Breast Cancer it contain 12,172 files.Manually doing clustering for all gene files is tedious.is there any way for giving each file as input to clustering algorithm one by one,saving the result to a file each time

Comment: Welcome to SO, this community would be happy to help with code however you need to show us what you tried first. You might be interested to check [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: You want to merge all 12k+ files into one single file and do the DBSCAN on that, right.  What kinds of files are you working with?  CSV?  Text?  Something else?

Comment: am working with text files